# Does pulldown menu have risk of MySQL injection

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I want my websites allow users to use pulldown menu to filter through a list of data provided by MySQL.  The choices from the pulldown menu is used in the following way:

```
$pulldown_choice = _GET['pulldown_choice'];
..... #other codes here
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE item LIKE '%$pulldown_choice%';
```

My question is: do I need to worry about database injection from the pre-defined, pulldown list choices?  Thanks!

Comment: You're best off using parameters for anything which you might want to concatenate into your SQL. So, basically, be safe and use parameterized queries, always.

Comment: Good point! Do the correct way and have a peaceful mind.

Comment: Obviously someone could pass in `*` and spoof your query.  So yes, you need to worry about injection here.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, I don't exactly understand how a "*" could be passed in from a pulldown menu with preset choices?  Can you give an example?

Comment: How about one that is coded poorly

Comment: How about an app that spoofs as your app and sends whatever it wants as parameters in an http get

Comment: You don't even need an app.  You could send a get from the JavaScript console.  Or you could use SOAP UI if feeling a bit more diabolical.

Answer (score 1):

Someone might tinker around with the request and manually invoke the URL with `...?pulldown_choice=WHATEVER_YOU_WANT` (e.g. `*`).

I probably would only pass an index and have the options on your server side fixed.

Comment: I do this all the time. It is far from uncommon but the average programmer never thinks about it imo

Comment: Your comments are eye openers for me.  I will definitely read more about this topic.